# Grammatische Analyse von »Es nimmt nicht wunder«

Tags: phrase

Ich bin soeben (wieder mal) über diese hübsche Floskel gestolpert:

> **Es nimmt nicht wunder,** *(dass dieser und jener Zusammenhang besteht.)*

Die Bedeutung ist wohl klar:

> **Niemand ist davon überrascht,** *(dass dieser und jener Zusammenhang besteht.)*

Aber wie ist diese Floskel grammatisch zu deuten? »Es« ist ganz offenbar ein Expletivum. Aber warum ist »wunder« hier kein Substantiv das großgeschrieben werden sollte? Wie würde dieser Satz in Futur I aussehen?

> a) Es wird nicht Wunder nehmen, ...
>   b) Es wird nicht wunder nehmen, ...
>   c) Es wird nicht wundernehmen, ...

Comment: nicht: *Es nimmt **mich** nicht wunder*?

Comment: @tofro: Nein, jedenfalls nicht zwingend. Optional kann man, wie mir Google verrät, anscheinend auch ein Reflexivpronomen in die Phrase packen, ohne dass das an der Bedeutung etwas verändert. Ich kannte die Phrase bisher eigentlich nur nicht-reflexiv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wundernehmen) ist *wundernehmen* erstaunlicherweise ein zusammengeschriebenes, trennbares Verb, das anscheinend sowohl reflexiv als auch nicht reflexiv verwendet werden kann (Das nimmt mich wunder, sic).

Danach ist *wunder* ein Wortbestandteil des Verbs und *kann* deshalb nicht groß geschrieben werden.

Comment: Deine Vermutung bezüglich der Rechtschreibreform passt nicht zum Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nimmt+nicht+wunder%2Cnimmt+nicht+Wunder&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnimmt%20nicht%20wunder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnimmt%20nicht%20Wunder%3B%2Cc0 - Jedenfalls wenn du die Reform von 1996 meinst. Zu 1901 würde es eher passen. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wundernehmen%2C+Wunder+nehmen&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwundernehmen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWunder%20nehmen%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ich habe auch gar nicht angedeutet, dass ein anders Wort als »es« ein Expletivum sein könnte.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich meinte die Zusammenschreibung als Ergebnis der RSR. Du hast nach getrennten Wortbestandteilen gesucht. Erstaunlicherweise findet ngrams aber für "wundernehmen" einen Berg um 1920.